# Just changed with a PAC but wrote in my number first

Tags: settings

I just bought a iPhone 4s and I changed from tmobile to Vodafone using a PAC code. I am now waiting for my new service. However I wrote in my number on the settings>my number. Will this effect my network transfer?

Answer (score 1):

No - the PAC code is related only to changing the number which routes to your SIM. The number you've entered into your phone isn't for anything other than as a reminder to yourself!